# Problem using fit_generator during keras training

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm working with very big text datasets. I thought about using `model.fit_generator` method instead of simple `model.fit`, so i tried using this generator:

```py
def TrainGenerator(inp, out):
  for i,o in zip(inp, out):
    yield i,o
```

When i try to use it during training using:

```py
#inp_train, out_train are lists of sequences padded to 50 tokens
model.fit_generator(generator = TrainGenerator(inp_train,out_train),
                    steps_per_epoch = BATCH_SIZE * 100,
                    epochs = 20,
                    use_multiprocessing = True)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_input to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Now, i tried using simple `model.fit` method, and it works fine. So, i think that my problem is in the generator but, since i'm new in using generators, i don't know how to solve it. The full model summary is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape            
===========================================
Embedding (Embedding)      (None, 50, 400)           
___________________________________________
Bi_LSTM_1 (Bidirectional)  (None, 50, 1024)          
___________________________________________
Bi_LSTM_2 (Bidirectional)  (None, 50, 1024)          
___________________________________________
Output (Dense)             (None, 50, 153)           
===========================================
```

Comment: Trye interate over input train and see the shape. i think that is a problem in the dimensions represetantation. but only if i see the data i can help.

Comment: Thanks @JúlioCesarPereiraRocha i can't explain why but your comment triggered me somehow! I edited the post.

Comment: @mao95 at BatchGenerator class, in def __len__(self) metod, float(self. is not completed.

Comment: @CanbeyBilgili sorry, didn't notice it, i edited the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I added the solution as edit to the question, for the sake of clarity I post it here as answer:

The first comment triggered me somehow. I realized that i misunderstood how generators work. The output of my generator was a list of shape 50, and not a list of N lists shaped 50. So i dug into keras documentation and found [this](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence). So, i changed my way of working and this is the class working as a generator:

```
class BatchGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        
        return batch_x, to_categorical(batch_y,num_labels)
```

Where `to_categorical` is the function:

```
def to_categorical(sequences, categories):
    cat_sequences = []
    for s in sequences:
        cats = []
        for item in s:
            cats.append(np.zeros(categories))
            cats[-1][item] = 1.0
        cat_sequences.append(cats)
    return np.array(cat_sequences)
```

So, what i noticed now is a good performance boost of my network, each epoch now lasts the half.